# Create disk space on Vagrant/VirtualBox guest

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant

I am looking to expand my VMs storage space and have done it the following way:

1. Moved Vagrant to an external hard drive
2. Reformatted the box to .vdi, resized it, formatted back to .vmdk
3. Re-added the box to VirtualBox
4. Started up my VM successfully

However, when trying to update the guest additions for VB I was unsuccessful in running the following command: `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup`

Upon running it the log generated indicated that I still did not have enough space, returning lines similar to the following in `/var/log/vbox-add-install.log`:

```
cp: writing `/tmp/vbox.0/include/iprt/mangling.h': No space left on device
```

At this point I've not much clue in what to do in order to completely add the extra storage space I thought I added when I reformatted it in step 2. Is there a step I'm missing? Would really appreciate help in getting this resolved

My guest machine is running Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm hosting on Mac

Comment: Follow [this Blog Post](http://trivialproof.blogspot.com/2011/01/resizing-virtualbox-virtual-hard-disk.html).  Resizing the `.vdi` file does not resize the partition in it.  If it works, I'll write up the simplified steps as an answer.

Comment: @eyoung100 will do and let you know, thank you

Comment: @eyoung100 I didn't have enough space even to install the gui for ubuntu in order to use gparted :P so I'm still in the process

Comment: so far i've destroyed the VM and re-upped, ran into a few issues and now back to a clean VM. will now install the gui and gparted first thing :)

Comment: Use a GParted LiveCD.  Mount the GParted ISO in the VirtualBox CDRom, and use it to resize the vdi

Comment: @eyoung100 I downloaded the GParted HD as I don't have a CD drive and am looking into it. If all else fails I can just run two VMs

Comment: @eyoung100 I did get to the point where I booted the VM and resized using GParted, however that was only by creating a VM separate from the one Vagrant uses. Was unsuccessful in the venture, will just stick with multiple VMs

Comment: Atleast the whole thing was enlightening, I got to learn tons about VirtualBox and Vagrant, and more confident in starting new VMs :D

Comment: I hate vagrant for this reason. I always create vm's manually